# Can we create an std::array of pointers to object in a constexpr function and return it?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, constexpr, compile-time

Suppose we have some sort of templated struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct S {};
```

We want to create an std::array of some object of type S. But, because S is a template struct, we need to create a base class for keeping those objects.

```
struct AbstractS {};

template<typename T>
struct S : AbstractS {};
```

Now, suppose that we have a constexpr function that creates an std::array and returns it and a constexpr function for get that array.

```
constexpr auto createArray() {
    constexpr auto v1 = S<int>{};
    constexpr auto v2 = S<double>{};
    std::array<const AbstractS *, 2> values{ &v1, &v2 };
    return values;
}

constexpr void getArray() {
    constexpr auto values = createArray();
}
```

This code doesn't compile and I think this is because the addresses of v1 and v2 are not constants.

Let me give you a concrete example of what I'm trying to do.

```
struct AbstractPolynomial {};

template<typename T, std::size_t Degree>
struct Polynomial : AbstractPolynomial {};
```

I have a struct that models a polynomial function, where T is type of values of coefficients of polynomial and Degree is the polynomial Degree.

```
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto createArray() {
    std::array<AbstractPolynomial *, N> polynomials;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            polynomials[i] = &Polynomials<T1>{5};
        } else {
            polynomials[i] = &Polynomials<T2>{2, 5};
        }
    }
    return polynomials;
}
```

Suppose that Polynomial has a deduction guide (I didn't implement it here). I know that you cannot get the address of a temporary and assigning lines are incorrect, but I put in this form because I want you to give me a solution for this scenario.

Can we do some sort of tricks to create a scenario like this?

Comment: return a `std::tuple<S<int>, S<double>>`?

Comment: I want something more generic because we can have more than 2 types.

Comment: What compiler error do you get?

Comment: std::array<...> is not a constant expression. @alfC

Comment: std::tuple can have more than 2 elements...

Comment: It's necessary that `values` (or `polinomials`) contains pointers to objects? Why not objects? I mean... what about `std::array<const AbstractS, 2> values{ S<int>{}, S<double>{} };`?

Comment: But now I can't use polymorphism anymore if I want to create some virtual methods.

Comment: @apopa, if you want virtual methods, spell it out. In any case 1) the chances to have  constexpr objects with virtual functions are slim 2) making static/compile time stuff use dynamic polymorphism is by definition a recipe to leave performance on the table. Thanks for further clarify the question but, please, write concrete working code, not hypothetical code. Like this https://godbolt.org/z/EqsnossY3 , which completes your second example. You are taking the address of a temporary, you can't do that, this is not java. Of course you can use `unique_ptr` but this is never going to be constexpr.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution, note that the Polynomials need to be generated initially preserving their compile-time type.
The later choice to not use that information for whatever reason (dynamic access) is yours.

Note the data structure is constexpr, but not necessarily the evaluation of the polynomial.
I think this is because `virtual` interferes with the `constexpr`-ness capabilities of the `evaluate` function.

You can play with the solution here: https://godbolt.org/z/oMreTzoGP

```
#include<array>
#include<cassert>
#include<tuple>
#include<utility>

// Dynamic polymials (questionable use of virtual functions)
struct AbstractPolynomial {
    virtual auto evaluate() const -> double = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Polynomial : AbstractPolynomial {
    constexpr Polynomial(T t) : value_{t}{}
    T value_;
    auto evaluate() const -> double override;
};

// instantiate and define two child classes for illustration
template<> auto Polynomial<double                   >::evaluate() const -> double {return value_;}
template<> auto Polynomial<std::pair<double, double>>::evaluate() const -> double {return value_.first + value_.second;}

// Metaprogramming in this block doesn't assume virtual functions, Polynomial can be a concrete class

// functional form (on index and constructor args) taken from OP example
constexpr auto makePoly(std::integral_constant<int, 0>){return Polynomial<double                   >{5.};}
constexpr auto makePoly(std::integral_constant<int, 1>){return Polynomial<std::pair<double, double>>({2., 5.});}

// Tuples (not arrays) are created here
template <std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto createTuple_aux(std::index_sequence<I...>){
    // do different things for even/odd cases (again taken from OP example)
    return std::make_tuple(makePoly(std::integral_constant<int, I % 2>{})...);
}
 
template <std::size_t N> constexpr auto createTuple(){return createTuple_aux(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});}

// create 10 non-polymorphic polynamials in a tuple (preserve type information)
constexpr auto polyTuple = createTuple<10>();

// create 10 polymorphic polynamials in an array via pointers (type information is kept in the virtual table in pointer elements)
constexpr auto polyArrayPtr = std::apply([](auto const&... e){return std::array<AbstractPolynomial const*, std::tuple_size<decltype(polyTuple)>{}>{&e...};}, polyTuple);

int main(){

// test non-polymorphic access
    assert( std::get<0>(polyTuple).evaluate() == 5. );
    assert( std::get<1>(polyTuple).evaluate() == 7. );
    assert( std::get<2>(polyTuple).evaluate() == 5. );

// test polymorphic access, indiraction 
    constexpr auto check = polyArrayPtr.size();

    assert( polyArrayPtr[0]->evaluate() == 5. );
    assert( polyArrayPtr[1]->evaluate() == 7. );
    assert( polyArrayPtr[2]->evaluate() == 5. );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @alfC . Your solution is brilliant, I need to study about std::index_sequence because I don't know how actually works, but thank you, I will try to use this :)

Comment: @apopa index_sequence is documented in cppreference.com. Feel free to accept or upvote the answer you like the most.

Comment: I can't upvote your answer right now because my account is almost new and I have only 11 points. When I reach more points, I will upvote your answer. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in `constexpr`. But intuition tells me your elements must be global and, for example, static to the function.

Since this is not possible in a `constexpr` function (the compiler tells me)  I put them outside and the whole thing works.

```
#include<array>

struct AbstractS {};

template<typename T>
struct S : AbstractS {};

namespace detail{
  constexpr auto v1 = S<int>{};
  constexpr auto v2 = S<double>{};
}

constexpr auto createArray() {
    constexpr std::array<const AbstractS *, 2> values{ &detail::v1, &detail::v2 };
    return values;
}

constexpr void getArray() {
    constexpr auto values = createArray();
}

int main(){}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1q6MbMhdM

Comment: Yes, I know that elements can be global and the program compiles, but I don't want global variables. Suppose we have hundreds of values. @alfC

Comment: @apopa, 1) static variables are global variable. 2) if they are dynamically generated (because they are hundreds) then they can't be constexpr. Without more context I can't help you. Not to mention that storing the base clase pointer is not really a solution because you have to store somewhere what the is exact type of the instance. I think you are looking for `std::tuple<S<int> , S<double> , ... >`.

Comment: Suppose you have this scenario:

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto f() {
    std::array<int, N> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
    return a;
}

I want to do something like this with scenario described in the original question. @alfC

Comment: @apopa, If your generated constexpr values are parameterized/generated by an integer then you can try with `std::index_sequence`. This requires a bit of meta-programming but I  don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @apopa whatever you are trying to do. Do it without constexpr first, and do it correctly, to show what you want to achieve.